# Ember sort data in router/ model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When the route `/facades` get visited I want to redirect to the first facade. This generally works, but as the list from the server is not sorted, my code doesn't redirect to the "first" facade. I know how to sort in the controller, but how can I sort in the router/ model by any property?

```
App.FacadesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @get("store").find("facade")

  redirect: ->
    facade = @modelFor("facades").get("firstObject")
    @transitionTo("facades.show", facade)
```

Answer (score 1):

redirect is deprecated, the recommendation is `afterModel`, and `findProperty` is super easy for finding a model in a collection based on some property in the model or if you don't know exactly you can use `sortBy`.

```
App.FacadesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @get("store").find("facade")

  afterModel: (model, transition) ->
    facade = model.findProperty("someproperty", "value on some property");
    // or
    facade = model.sortBy("someproperty").get('firstObject');
    @transitionTo("facades.show", facade)
```

Comment: What if I don't know "value on some property" but want to use the first one (sorted alphabetically for example)?

Comment: sortBy was added in ember 1.2.0, which does not yet work with emblemjs. At least I get a compilation error when upgrading to 1.2.0 :(

Comment: Well, that's a buzz kill, especially since handlebars hasn't changed since 1.0.  Hah, I'd probably just use toArray then javascript's sort.   The array proxy seems like a lot of overhead, but honestly I'd just leave it in until you can upgrade then switch to sortBy

Comment: One more question: afterModel fires only when the model needs to be loaded. So it works for the first visit, but all following vists to the route don't trigger afterModel. How to make the route to always redirect?

Comment: afterModel happens any time the model/route changes.  If the model/route doesn't change afterModel doesn't happen.

Comment: What other visits to the route are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just found a way which works. Not sure if it's the best, but I think this could be useful to others too:

```
App.FacadesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @get("store").find("facade")

  redirect: ->
    sortedFacades = Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins Ember.SortableMixin,
      sortProperties: ["id"]
      content: @modelFor("facades")
    facade = sortedFacades.get("firstObject")
    @transitionTo("facades.show", facade)
```